# android read/save internal storage

Tags: android, file, save, internal-storage

I need to save file into internal storage, an then read it.
For save it i do something like this:

```
        // Create directory into internal memory;
        File mydir = getActivity().getDir("modelli", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File a = new File(mydir, obj_id);
        a.mkdir();

        File b = new File(mydir, obj_id);
        if (obj_type != "modello"){

            b = new File(a,obj_type);
            b.mkdir();

        }


        String filename = "";
        if(obj_imageName != null) 
        {
            filename = obj_imageName + "." + getFileExtension(urlString);
        }
        else 
        {
            filename = getFileName(urlString);
        }

        final File file = new File(b, filename);
        file.createNewFile();
```

but I don't know how read it, with this I get an error (contains a path separator):

```
File mydir = getActivity().getDir("app_modelli/2/images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

where is the mistake? is correct my approach for write file?

Answer (score 0):

You better put them in internal files dir. Both for writing and reading you could use a File object like:

```
 String fileName = "info.txt";

 File file = new File ( getInternalFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);
```

At the moment your code only creates a file with length 0. You are not writing/saving anything to it.